# How to call __autoload() in php code

Tags: php, autoload, autoloader

I am new to php and I want to use php5's __autoload functionality in my code. I wrote below code in my index.php but I don't understand how and when I should call __autoload function.

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if (file_exists($class . '.php')) {
        include($class . '.php');
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to load class named $class');
    }
}
```

I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753269/how-will-this-autoload-function) also but I do not have such autoloader class in my application. Do every application need a separate class in order to use autoloading? If not can I have a single function like above and complete it's task? 
Can anyone explain how to call above __autoload function inside my php code?

Comment: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't call `__autoload()` yourself, PHP does when it is trying to find the implementation of a class.

For example...

```
function __autoload($className) {
     include $className . '.php';
}

$customClass = new CustomClass;
```

...this will call `__autoload()`, passing `CustomClass` as an argument. This (stupid for example's sake) `__autoload()` implementation will then attempt to include a file by tacking the `php` extension on the end.

As an aside, you should use `spl_autoload_register()` instead. You can then have multiple implementations, useful when using multiple libraries with auto loaders.

> ...using `__autoload()` is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: `__autoload()` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)

Comment: @RaghavendraN Yep, `spl_autoload_register()` is better. See last paragraph.

Answer (score 9):

In PHP __autoload() is a magic method, means it gets called automatically when you try create an object of the class and if the PHP engine doesn't find the class in the script it'll try to call __autoload() magic method.

You can implement it as given below example:

```
function __autoload($ClassName)
{
    include($ClassName.".php");
}

$CustomClassObj = new CustomClass();
$CustomClassObj1 = new CustomClass1();
$CustomClassObj2 = new CustomClass2();
```

It'll automatically include all the class files when creating new object.

P.S. For this to work you'll have to give class file name same as the class name.

Answer (score 3):

You guys need to use `require_once` instead of `include` which will eat your memory
The best way is:

```
function __autoload($class) {
   $class_name = strtolower($class);
   $path       = "{$class}.php";
   if (file_exists($path)) {
       require_once($path);
   } else {
       die("The file {$class}.php could not be found!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you get the lowercase version of the class name, then not use it?  Did you intend to test both paths?

Comment: because it stops you from creating `cLaSS_nAme.php` file :)

Comment: Actually, if you had said `$path = "${class_name}.php";` I would agree.  I asked since you use `"${class}.php"` instead, which allows the oddly cased file name.

Answer (score 1):

also you can use `spl_autoload_register()` for load php file and this is much better than
`__autoload` for example :

```
<?php 
spl_autoload_register('myautoloadClass::myautoloadMethod');

class myautoloadClass{

   public static function myautoloadMethod(){
   require_once 'yourPath/'.'yourphpFile'.'.php';
   }

}

$obj = new xp; 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use __autoload() instead use spl_autoload_register. [See php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which says

spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

```
    <?php

    // function __autoload($class) {
    //     include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    // }

    function my_autoloader($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    }

    spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

    // Or, using an anonymous function as of PHP 5.3.0
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    });

    ?>
```

Comment: I think the word 'flexible' means that you can use your own implemented function as autoloader.